# How to start docker-machine on OSX?

Tags: macos, docker, osx-elcapitan, docker-machine

I've installed and use docker for the first time yesterday,

Everything was working properly, but yesterday night I've shutdown my computer.

Today I start it and I wanted to work on my docker app, But when I try to run it like

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 container/app`

I got the error :

> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.

But I can't find how to launch docker again...

Ideas ?

EDIT :

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

result:

> Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running

Comment: https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1010

Comment: see edit -> Already checked this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eval "$(docker-machine env default)" leads to Error checking TLS connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058492/eval-docker-machine-env-default-leads-to-error-checking-tls-connection)

Comment: `docker-machine ls` should give you a list of machines that are configured. If a machine is stopped, run `docker-machine start <name-of-machine>` please read the documentation https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Comment: @thaJeztah - you should post your comment as an answer. It's the correct solution imo.

Comment: @maml ah, yes, perhaps I should

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `docker-machine env default` command won't work if the "default" machine is not running.

You can run the `docker-machine ls` command, which should give you a list of machines that are configured, and their current status (running, stopped).

If a machine is stopped, run `docker-machine start <name-of-machine>`. After that you should be able to set the environment variables using

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

please read the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview for more details

Comment: I did , docker-machine ls then , `docker-machine start <name-of-machine>`
Mine was still complaining Something went wrong running an SSH command! Running following commands solved it:
`docker-machine restart` then
`eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`

Answer (score 1):

After I run the command `$ docker-machine start default`, I get the message of

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is supposed to fix this issue
```

A solution is provided at the end of the message,

```
This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is supposed to fix this issue
```

I uninstall and then, try to reinstall the `VirtualBox`. It was still same.

Then, I allowed the apps from anywhere in the machine and this solved the issue:

Allow Apps from Anywhere: `sudo spctl --master-disable`

[image]